# Save excel file with datatables

Tags: jquery, html, excel

Is it possible with Datatables to save the Excel fil in a defined location without the save as popup. (I run the html file local)

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/flash/filename.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example'String).DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip'String,
    buttons: [
 {
extend: 'excelFlash'String,
filename: 'Data export'String
},
{
 extend: 'pdfFlash'String,
 filename: 'Data export'String
}
]
});
});
```

Comment: You want to create the File direct at the HDD of the user? Without asking the user where he/she want the File? This isn't possible, and its good :)

Comment: Yes. Its possible with PHPexcel. The html file is on a USBstick so I need to save it on that.